# Why my page blank when I use looping?

Tags: php, mysqli

I make a looping system in my localhost use **xampp** and it's work in my friend localhost also work. but when I upload it to hosting it's not working and when I try in mac local host, it not working to.

my looping system is very simple.

```
<?php
include 'koneksi.php';
    $tampil=$db->query("SELECT * FROM soal ORDER BY Rand()");
    while($data=$tampil->fetch_object()){
    ?>
            <h3>hallo</h3>
            <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: normally a blank page is some error - but your environment might have turn off error reporting.

Comment: Make your youre database connection works fine on your server.

Comment: Get a better picture of what is going on by using var_dump, ie. var_dump($tampil); and you could also forget the loop for now and just define $data=$tampil->fetch_object() and on the next line var_dump($data). Should give you a better insight.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: its because your connection on the live hosting is incorrect